# Error- Run Time Exception Error (Possible Bind Butterknife)

Tags: java, android, bind, butterknife

**I am running into this problem. I am getting a Java RuntimeException Error. Here is the Error Log**

```
04-22 21:11:02.129  17677-17677/com.example.andrewjakevillegas.stormy E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.andrewjakevillegas.stormy, PID: 17677

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.andrewjakevillegas.stormy/com.example.andrewjakevillegas.stormy.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to bind views for com.example.andrewjakevillegas.stormy.MainActivity
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2790)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2855)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to bind views for com.example.andrewjakevillegas.stormy.MainActivity

            at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:322)
            at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:237)
            at com.example.andrewjakevillegas.stormy.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6374)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2855)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view 'timeLabel' with ID 2131230803 for field 'mTimeLabel' was not found. If this view is optional add '@Nullable' annotation.

            at butterknife.ButterKnife$Finder.findRequiredView(ButterKnife.java:140)
            at com.example.andrewjakevillegas.stormy.MainActivity$$ViewBinder.bind(MainActivity$$ViewBinder.java:11)
            at com.example.andrewjakevillegas.stormy.MainActivity$$ViewBinder.bind(MainActivity$$ViewBinder.java:8)
            at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:319)
            at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:237)
            at com.example.andrewjakevillegas.stormy.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6374)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2855)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
04-22 21:11:05.309  17677-17677/com.example.andrewjakevillegas.stormy I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 17677 SIG: 9
```

**Here is my MainActivity.java**

```
        package com.example.andrewjakevillegas.stormy;

        import android.app.DownloadManager;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
        import android.net.NetworkInfo;
        import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        import org.json.JSONException;
        import org.json.JSONObject;
        import org.w3c.dom.Text;

        import java.io.IOException;

        import butterknife.Bind;
        import butterknife.ButterKnife;
        import okhttp3.Call;
        import okhttp3.Callback;
        import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
        import okhttp3.Request;
        import okhttp3.Response;


    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private CurrentWeather mCurrentWeather;

    @Bind(R.id.timeLabel) TextView mTimeLabel;
    @Bind(R.id.temperatureLabel) TextView mTemperatureLabel;
    @Bind(R.id.humidityValue) TextView mHumidityValue;
    @Bind(R.id.precipValue) TextView mPrecipValue;
    @Bind(R.id.summaryLabel) TextView mSummaryLabel;
    @Bind(R.id.iconImageView) TextView mIconImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        String apiKey = "6742d289456f597f5aca440dc97c2b3b";
        double latitude = 37.8267;
        double longitude = -122.423;
        String forecastURL = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/" + apiKey +
                "/" + latitude + "," + longitude;

        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(forecastURL)
                    .build();

            Call call = client.newCall(request);
            call.enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                    try {
                        String jsonData = response.body().string();
                        Log.v(TAG, jsonData);
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            mCurrentWeather = getCurrentDetails(jsonData);
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    updateDisplay();
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            alertUserAboutError();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught: ", e);
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e){
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught: ", e);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.network_unavailable_message),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Main UI code is running!");

    }

    private void updateDisplay() {
        mTemperatureLabel.setText(mCurrentWeather.getTemperature() +"");
    }

    private CurrentWeather getCurrentDetails(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        String timezone = forecast.getString("timezone");
        Log.i(TAG, "From JSON: " + timezone);

        JSONObject currently = forecast.getJSONObject("currently");
        CurrentWeather currentWeather = new CurrentWeather();
        currentWeather.setHumidity(currently.getDouble("humidity"));
        currentWeather.setTime(currently.getLong("time"));
        currentWeather.setIcon(currently.getString("icon"));
        currentWeather.setPrecipChance(currently.getDouble("precipProbability"));
        currentWeather.setSummary(currently.getString("summary"));
        currentWeather.setTemperature(currently.getDouble("temperature"));

        return new CurrentWeather();
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isAvailable = false;
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()){
            isAvailable = true;
        }

        return isAvailable;
    }

    private void alertUserAboutError() {
        AlertDialogFragment dialog = new AlertDialogFragment();
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "error_dialog");
    }
}
```

**Here is my activity_main.xml - this is my layout.**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".MainActivity"
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
                android:background="#fffc970b">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="100"
        android:id="@+id/temperatureLabel"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="150dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/degreeImageView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/temperatureLabel"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/temperatureLabel"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/temperatureLabel"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/degree"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="At 5:00 PM it will be"
        android:id="@+id/timeLabel"
        android:layout_above="@+id/temperatureLabel"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#95ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Alcatraz Island, CA"
        android:id="@+id/locationLabel"
        android:layout_above="@+id/timeLabel"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/iconImageView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/locationLabel"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/cloudy_night"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/temperatureLabel"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="HUMIDITY"
                android:id="@+id/humidityLabel"
                android:textColor="#95ffffff"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0.88"
                android:id="@+id/humidityValue"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RAIN/SNOW?"
                android:id="@+id/precipLabel"
                android:textColor="#95ffffff"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="100"
                android:id="@+id/precipValue"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Stormy with a chance of meatballs"
        android:id="@+id/summaryLabel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**And here is my AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.andrewjakevillegas.stormy" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.**

Comment: I hoped the provided answer is solved your problem.

Comment: Thank you Avi! I know I am having a different problem. Let me sort out what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used

```
@Bind(R.id.iconImageView) TextView mIconImageView;
```

For:-

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/iconImageView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/locationLabel"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/cloudy_night"/>
```

It should be

```
@Bind(R.id.iconImageView) ImageView mIconImageView;
```

You are taking wrong View type for mIconImageView it should be ImageView instead of TextView.